# Different behaviour when using a command line script or running it from a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, backgroundworker, errorlevel

I have a really weird problem which recquire a strong knowledge of C# 's backgroundworker.

I want to run a command line program and check its ERRORLEVEL.

`cmd.exe /c echo Launching the command && COMMAND_TO_RUN  & echo Connexion statut : && echo %ERRORLEVEL% && if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (echo FAILURE) ELSE (echo SUCCESS))`

When the command fail, the ERRORLEVEL get the value -1

This works when I use this line in the cmd.exe.

But, here is the problem.

When I use a background worker to run this line, the ERRORLEVEL take the value 0 even if the COMMAND_TO_RUN fail.

Here is my backgroundworker code :

```
string[] args = { "/c echo Launching the command && COMMAND_TO_RUN  & echo Connexion statut : && echo %ERRORLEVEL% && if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (echo FAILURE) ELSE (echo SUCCESS))};
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(args);


 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = e.Argument as string[];
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
        process.Start();
        System.IO.StreamReader sOut = process.StandardOutput;

        string tempOut;
        while (!sOut.EndOfStream)
        {
            // using the report progress userstate allow me to catch 
            // the program output in runtime
            tempOut = sOut.ReadLine();
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, tempOut);
        }
        process.Close();
    }
```

So Does the use of a backgroundworker lead to a particular value of the ERRORLEVEL ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't compare `BackgrounWorker` to manual *run line in cmd.exe*. Instead call listed code directly in place where you create `BackgroundWorker`. And expected result: it will not work and it has nothing to do with `BackgroundWorker` ;)

Comment: The problem is I have an UI communicating with my COMMAND_TO_LAUNCH and the program to launch can take quite some time, so the easier way for me to run the program without freezing my UI is to use a backgroundworker.

Comment: Your intentions are clear. But blaming `BackgroundWorker` is not fair without making sure first =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about BackgroundWorker (sorry), there are at least three problems with the command part:

1. Depending on the real `COMMAND_TO_RUN`, maybe it is not executed inside the `cmd` spawned instance and, independtly of it, the spawned `cmd` instance has ended its execution without problems so the errorlevel you get in your C# code, the exit code from `cmd`, can be 0.
2. When the line is readed by `cmd`, it is parsed and then executed. In the parse phase, all the variable read operations are removed from the command to be executed and replaced by the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the line. So, all your `%errorlevel%` reads (that are all in the same line) do not change when you run your `COMMAND_TO_RUN` and will return the value in the variable before the command execution.
3. There is a concatenation problem. `A & B` is used to concatenate command execution, that is, `run A, when finished run B`. But `A && B` means `run A and if not errorlevel then run B` (`A && B || C` means `run A, if not errorlevel run B, else run C`)

Try with something like this (`dir` is the command that will fail)

```
cmd.exe /c "echo Launching the command & (( dir *.notexist >nul 2>nul  )&&( echo SUCCESS & exit /b 0 )||( echo FAILURE & exit /b 1 ))"
```

Comment: Well, i know the difference between & and && , and I purposedly used them both in my command line. Indeed I could use the && after my COMMAND_TO_LAUNCH to echo a success message, but I would prefer to echo a message if the command fail. The weird thing is that the command line works perfectly fine when used in a console...

Comment: @Raizyl, no, it does not work from command line. Run this simplification from your code in command line `cmd /c "dir *.notexist & echo status && echo %errorlevel%"` : when parsed `%errorlevel%` will be replaced by the value it has before the execution of the failing command (dir), the `dir` is executed and errorlevel is set (but you will not see it), `echo` is executed and if the `echo` does not fail (the `&&` problem, it follows the `echo`, not the `dir`) echo status with a wrong `%errorlevel%` (the value before the execution). And the `cmd` will end with a errorlevel of 0

Comment: Well, when I try your command line, i get an errorlevel value of -1, so it seems to work. By the way, your solution with using && and then || seems to work ! i have to test it further, but it gives me hope ^^ thanks !

Comment: I think the commad "echo" does not have an exit return value so it doesn't affect the errorlevel. At least, that's what I found out through testing. But you seems to say that it can affect the errorlevel. It could be bothersome for me since my program should behave the same on all the computer at work. Do you know more about this ?

Comment: @Raizyl. No, it does not affect the errorlevel inside the running instance of `cmd`. But if the last command executed in the `cmd` does not set an errorlevel, the `cmd` instance ends with errorlevel 0. Save this as `test.cmd` file: `dir *.nono`. Run the batch file as `test.cmd` and as `cmd /c test.cmd`. After each run use `echo %errorlevel%` You will see 1 in both cases. Now, edit the batch file and append a `echo test`. Now there will be a difference. Directly calling the batch keeps the errorlevel 1 after the run, but after `cmd /c test.cmd` the `echo %errorlevel%` will show 0

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand better now the stack of call affecting the errorlevel.